# Kentico API replacement for CMS.OnlineForms.BizForm.BasicForm

Tags: kentico

`viewBiz  = new CMS.OnlineForms.BizForm;`(in ascx control)

`viewBiz.BasicForm` throws error saying

> 'CMS.OnlineForms.BizForm' does not contain a definition for 'BasicForm'.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Basic form is under `CMS.FormControls.BasicForm` not `CMS.OnlineForms.BizForm`.